# How to restrict users and admin from creating new taxonomy terms?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms

I've created taxonomy (schedule_day_taxonomy) for a specific custom post type (schedule).

```
add_action( 'init', 'schedule_day_tax_func' );
function schedule_day_tax_func() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'schedule_day_taxonomy',
        'schedule',
        array(
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'label' => 'Day',
            'query_var' => true,
        )
    );
}
```

Now the taxonomy `DAY` appears only in the custom post type `schedule`
I've created `7 terms' from the admin panel.

[image: Days]

Now I want to remove `Add New Category` option permanently for all the users and admin.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This check:

```
    <?php if ( current_user_can( $taxonomy->cap->edit_terms ) ) : ?>
```

needs to be satisfied to display the "*Add New Category*" link.

You can set the *capabilities* for your `schedule_day_taxonomy` taxonomy, when you register it.

### Example

Only users with the `edit_schedule_day_taxonomy` capability can edit the taxonomy:

```
add_action( 'init', 'schedule_day_tax_func' );
function schedule_day_tax_func() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'schedule_day_taxonomy',
        'post',
        array(
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'label' => 'Day',
            'query_var' => true,
            'capabilities' => array(
                'edit_terms' => 'edit_schedule_day_taxonomy',
            ),
        )
    );
}
```

Without this capability, users can't edit this taxonomy. If you need to edit it, you can remove this from the code above or assign it to your *admin* user.